# Display object property in modal

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a modal from ngx-bootstrap that I want to display in there a property of my object let's say the name:

```
public students = [
    { id: 1, name: 'lorem'}
```

In this button that is common for all the entris in the table (each row has this button) that opens a modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">View student's name</button>
```

What I've tried was to do:

```
<div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let student of students">
    {{student.name}}
</div>
```

but it displays all of the names in my array when I click the button, and I just want the one I'm clicking in for that row.

How can I access the property when I click in the button? Add the Student model parameter to the openModal function? If so, how to select the current student I'm clicking in? The modal function looks like this:

```
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
    // Pass student as arg to display on modal???

  }
```

Any help?

Edit:
Ok it works passing the student in the modal function, but then I want to display the name here:

```
<ng-template #template>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h1>{{student}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">         
            Close
        </button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

So only If I type this line it displays the name, otherwise it isn't recognised in the html above (ng-template)

```
this.student = student.name;
```

I would like to do {{student.name}} inside my ng-template

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below details will help you

```
public students = [
{ id: 1, name: 'lorem'} 
{ id: 2, name: 'cali'} 
{ id: 3, name: 'johan'} 
{ id: 4, name: 'pia'} ];

public student =  { };
```

so you have a screen there have the list of students,

```
<div  *ngFor="let student of students">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template, student)">View student's name</button></div>
```

as soon as you click on any of the students, it will pass a template with particular selected student details to the component and from there you will set you student value there.

```
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>, student) {
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
// Pass student as arg to display on modal???
this.student = student;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the file component.ts**

I define a variable with name of toDisplayGroup

```
 export class MentorComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(private gorupservice: GroupService) {}

     ngOnInit(): void {
    
     }
   ...
     toDisplayGroup = {};
   ...            
}
```

**in the file component.hml**

I define a function within div.row: (click)="toDisplayGroup = group". At the same time I add the modal trigers code to here:

```
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let group of groups" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    <div class="col-md-6" (click)="toDisplayGroup = group">
    {{group.groupname}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    {{group.groupId}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**And Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{toDisplayGroup['groupname']}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```